# Titanium Mobile - Simulator exits without error

Tags: objective-c, image, debugging, image-processing, titanium

I have following problem:

In my titanium project I save an image ( from UIView.toImage() ) to a file in applicationDirectory. Then I have a Obj-C module, where I read out that file. 
Then an image processing algorithm is applied from a C++ Lib.

Before the algorithm is applied to the image I have a function which gets the ARGB-values from
the values I get from the file. I make a Pixel Matrix out of them.

Then, after the algorithm is applied I transform the new Pixel Matrix back into an UIImage to save it to a file.

My problem is, that sometimes the program crashes BEFORE the algorithm is applied (I use NSLogs to see where it crashes, that is right, isn't it? ) and sometimes the whole Obj-C Module finishes its work ...

I don't get any error message in the Titanium Console... Is there some way to see why I get the crashs or is there a way to debug my titanium project efficiently?

Comment: That was true when you wrote that, bh88, but isn't true anymore. We listened to the community, and decided to release debugging for everyone to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I debug the modules that I work on by running my test project in XCode. When the app crashes, XCode will break at some unhelpful spot. BUT what is helpful is the stack trace. I can usually clean enough information from that to figure out what is going wrong, and where.

Let me be explicit about "test project".
- If you are running your module by doing "titanium run" from the terminal, I will open the generated project in XCode and run it from there (you'll see the path to it in the generated log statements after you "titanium run" your module). 
- Or, if you have your module as part of an actual project, build the project once, and open it in XCode. Run it, crash it, and you'll get a stack trace to help you on your way.

Another option would be for you to stick your really problematic code in some of the core Titanium Mobile code -- like in the PlatformModule.m. This is a module like your own, except its source code is right there. Then you'll be able set breakpoints, inspect your variables, and enjoy the full benefits of using XCode to see what's going on in your objective-c.

I hope this helps, and gets you on your way! Let me know if I can clarify anything further. -Dawson